# Does the producer demand to have the trick explained before hand, privately?

Tags: production, penn-and-teller-fool-us

I watched an episode of Penn & Teller: Fool Us where a magician fools Penn and Teller and the only explanation that seems possible to anyone is that the randomly chosen audience member involved is a "plant" (someone predisposed to the trick).

However:

- Penn and Teller claim that they're confident that the audience member involved is not a plant.
- I've heard that plants are not allowed in the show.
- I've heard that to avoid tricks that involve breaking the show's rules, the magician must explain to the show's producer (or a magician employee perhaps) how the trick works before hand, privately.

So, can anyone confirm whether or not that third bullet is accurate?

Comment: Considering the prize is the right to put on a show at P&T's Las Vegas show, that seems like shooting yourself in the foot to break the rules. And anyone in the industry would balk at telling a non-magician the trick, let alone someone that may steal the trick.

Comment: @cde true but we're talking about a show run by Pen and Teller. The producer *is* (from what I heard via unreliable source) a magician also, and on top of Pen and Teller's integrity as world famous magicians, an NDA could be involved as well. So it seems at least plausible.

Comment: Out of curiosity, which magician is the one described in your question? Was it one of the ones from the first episode of the new season?

Comment: @CarlFink It was [Nick Einhorn](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OpTOQGAfIPE)

Comment: In the first and second season, they did refer to the third magician to see if their guesses were correct.  It didnt happen often.

Comment: @CarlFink I just read a YouTube comment on another episode of the show where someone mentions that  Nick Einhorn actually did break the rules and use planted members of the audience, and his victory was later nullified. fyi

Comment: I found [an explanation of Nick Einhorn's trick](https://web.archive.org/web/20130112234252/http://mymagic.sytes.net/PennTellerFoolUs/NickEinhorn/). The close-up screenshot of the first table's note seems to confirm that this explanation is more or less correct, and that Einhorn didn't use audience plants.

Comment: @CarlFink that seems to be theoretical. Because that relies on the audience members all cooperating, not giggling about it, etc.

Comment: @Viziionary The screenshot shows that the man at Table 1 has a note that says on the bottom "WHICH LEAVES (Please say your name) SITTING AT TABLE NUMBER 3, WHERE HE'LL ENJOY A PIZZA." It's clear as day, I can even capture a 1080p screenshot which is slightly higher-resolution than the version on that site.  The only part that isn't really legible is "please say your name," but whatever that text says, it's in a different font and obviously isn't actually the guy's name.

Comment: Of course you're right that it relies on the audience members playing along. I'm no psychology expert, but I guess the people overwhelmingly do so--obviously enough for Einhorn to trust this trick to work on national television.

Comment: @CarlFink Yeah, but are we sure there wasnt an audience plant as well? Because one thing that did back up the rumor: These P&T episodes are sort of prized possessions of these magicians. P&T give each contestant their episode to host on their own YouTube channels. Einhorn has a channel, but the video is not there. Maybe he was forced to take it down and something about his act did indeed have him disqualified.

Comment: We can be reasonably sure of that, since there's no reason to print all three lines on all three notes if the magician has control over which note ends up at which table (as he would if he used a plant).

And that's not even counting the fact that audience plants are (as I understand it) disallowed by the show's rules.  Given that the magicians explain their methods ahead of time to Johnny Thompson, it's difficult to understand how a trick which relies on a plant could have gotten past the producers.

Comment: @CarlFink even so, I read that his success on the show was later nullified and his trophy revoked (in YT comments) and isn't that a rather specific thing to just make up? So I was interested enough to [ask a question about it.](http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/57139/how-did-this-violation-of-the-penn-teller-fool-us-rules-get-past-the-screen)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're exactly correct.  Magic expert [Johnny Thompson](http://www.simonpierro.com/penn-teller-fool-us) is the one who knows how the tricks work and makes the call on whether or not Penn & Teller have been fooled:

> For *Fool Us*, Johnny interviews each magician, and finds out how each trick is done.  During the broadcast, Penn & Teller confer with Johnny, and he confirms whether they’ve correctly guessed how the trick was done or not.