# How did this violation of the "Penn & Teller: Fool Us" rules get past the screening process?

Tags: penn-and-teller-fool-us

I recently asked "[Does the producer demand to have the trick explained before hand, privately?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/57093/does-the-producer-demand-to-have-the-trick-explained-before-hand-privately?noredirect=1#comment90127_57093)", where [it was confirmed](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/57112/20578) there is a screening process for the show in which the contestant magician must explain the trick to a "3rd party" magician, Johnny Thompson, who verifies whether or not Penn & Teller have been fooled in case of dispute, and presumably ensures that the trick follows the shows guidelines.

1. I *think* it's against the rules to plant assistants in the audience and then pick them at "random" on the show.
2. Interestingly, my original reason for asking the question I linked above was to learn whether the "random" audience member in Nick Einhorn's P&T:FU performance could have been a plant. Since the answer to my question was "Yes, there's a guy working for P&T who verifies the trick before hand.", I came to the conclusion "Wow, that was a legit trick."
3. However, I later heard (in a YouTube comment) that the "random" audience members in Nick Einhorn's trick were later discovered to have been his assistants, and Pen and Teller nullified his award for fooling them. My source is far from reliable, but that *does* seem like a rather specific rumor to just make up.

So, if the details in **#1**, **#2**, & **#3** are accurate, it doesn't make sense to me how Nick Einhorn's trick could have made it past the screening process.

---

Are those points each accurate, and if so:

How did he get on the show if he had to explain his trick to a magician before hand who would verify that it could be used on the show?

Comment: Can you link to the YouTube comment? What leads you to believe it is reliable given that it appears to contradict points #1 & #2?

Comment: @CarlFink Two facts: 1) It seems too specific to be made up in a comment like that 2) Einhorn uniquely does not host the video of his P&T episode on his YouTube channel as all of the other magicians seem to do. This leads me to believe it could've been taken down. And I wish I could link you to the comment, but it was a response to a comment on a different video that I watched much later, and I watched like 25 episodes on YT, no idea which one it was now.

Comment: I really think the answer is that the YouTube commenter was (consciously or otherwise) just wrong. Especially given the link in your other question which demonstrates pretty strongly that the trick does not require an audience plant. I'll be interested to learn of any solid evidence that Einhorn's victory was rescinded.

Comment: I'd also be interested to see solid evidence for point #1, which I, too, believe to be correct but haven't seen confirmed for sure.

Comment: It could be that the trick is easier with a plant, or they arnt required to *perform* the trick for the 3rd Party, just a reasonable explanation. Or that the guy couldn't trick Johnny. If he can fool P&T, then he could just as easily fool Johnny. He's not infallible, and magic is all about misdirection.

Comment: Einhorn does not appear to be unique in not hosting a video of his Fool Us appearance on YouTube. A quick search reveals that several others (some of whom fooled P&T, in case that might make a difference) have YouTube channels without their Fool Us clips: [Piff the Magic Dragon](https://www.youtube.com/user/piffthemagicdragon/videos), [Morgan & West](https://www.youtube.com/user/MrMorganandMrWest/videos), [Shawn Farquhar](https://www.youtube.com/user/ShawnFarquhar/videos) (he has a clip of his recent season 3 appearance, but not of his original season 1 one).

Comment: This question is based entirely on this highly dubious premise: *I later heard (in a YouTube comment) that the "random" audience members in Nick Einhorn's trick were later discovered to have been his assistants, and Pen and Teller nullified his award for fooling them.* For which we have zero evidence (not even the claimed YouTube comment). I've no idea why this question has been so highly upvoted.

Answer (score 9):

Just to clarify. The trick was legit, no plants, no lies.

> A man by the name (say your name) will be instructed to sit at table number (say your table number) where he will be served (read label on back of metal tray).

That's it...the whole trick. No plants at all, the guy saying the FU title was nullified is lying

Comment: [This explanation of the trick](https://web.archive.org/web/20130112234252/http://mymagic.sytes.net/PennTellerFoolUs/NickEinhorn/), linked to in a comment on the asker's previous question, includes a screenshot of the note.  While it does say, "please say your name," it also clearly includes the actual table number and food item mentioned, not just placeholders.  The explanation includes a description of how this could have been achieved (namely by using 18 envelopes instead of only 3, and including 3 messages on each note).

Comment: An extremely dangerous method, because there WILL be smartasses who read out the note literally.

Comment: @Develobba (I've been rewatching the show and found this thread). Actually - table 3 did get a pizza, so all they had to do was insert their names. They might not be stooges, but he was lucky they were willing to comply.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Picture attached is screenshot from the show: specifically the yellow note which table 1 was asked to read. As you can see, each piece of paper has all three tables' instructions on it, and it asks them to 'please say your name'

Answer (score -1):

This type of volunteer is called an "Instant Stooge", so they're still a stooge by definition.

Comment: How is this an answer to the question "How did he get on the show..."?